# await function in Python

Tags: python, tornado, requesthandler

So this is some code i have in my python file, the details of the code aren't that important, I basically use this MainHandler to deal with some requests sent to it by a connection "client".

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
   #some code
   async def connect(self):
      client = self.request.connection.stream
      #some code
      data = await client.read_bytes(10000, partial = True)
```

My doubt is if there's a way of waiting for the client.read_bytes() while a condition is still met. When that condition fails, I need to stop the "await".

Comment: So you want to cancel the `await` if something in particular happens? You probably need to [`cancel`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.cancel) the task somehow.

Comment: actually, I want to continue the waiting while a condition is true, if it gets false I want to stop waiting. I'm trying right now catching the exception that appears in the  await  when the client closes, because the exception itself isn't that harmful to my program.

Comment: But how does the condition change in your program? Is it in another task? Or something out of asyncio, or out of Python? How is it checked?

Comment: It was something I could verify with client.closed(), so while the client wasn't closed, I would need to keep waiting for data. But I solved it for now by catching the exception that the await raises. Thanks!

Comment: @am.torrinha If you want to cancel `await` when the connection is closed, only way to do it is by catching the exception.